# Questions asking "Has anyone else experienced this?"

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I'm seeing a fair number of questions that describe a problem then ask whether anyone else has experienced the problem. This invites a host of "yes, I've had that problem" (or worse, but less common, "no, that hasn't happened to me") answers. Ordinarily "I've got that problem too" gets deleted as a non-answer, but in this case, it actually answers the OP's question.

The problem is,the question as asked literally invites all of humanity to chime in with yes, me too or no, not me. This is not a question that provokes helpful answers.

What can we do to discourage the question "has anyone else experienced this problem" in favor of something that provokes better responses?

Answer (score 3):

It may be enough to just have a look at the Help Center entry about [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

> [...] avoid asking subjective questions where ...
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”
> - **there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”**
> - you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”
> - your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”

So I would invite everybody to either edit these kind of questions into something which can be answered in a way which solves the problem or at least flag those questions. And (because the site is supposed to be self-moderating) I want to encourage everybody to give the "edit" option a try :-)

Answer (score 1):

We have one site-specific close reason left which we could actually use to close questions which do not ask for an actual solution. Kind of like the "not a real question" reason we had in the past, but a bit more specific.

PS: Had to use two different answers to give people a chance to upvote answers based on preferences